# can the Spring XD jdbc sink use native authentication with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, spring-xd

I'm trying to create the following stream to test my db connection

```
stream create --name dbtest --definition "time --fixedDelay=10 | jdbc --url='jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:54732;instanceName=1LLENSBROWN\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=XMLTestDatabase;integratedSecurity=true;' --driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" --deploy
```

when I deploy the stream I get an error saying "This driver is not configured for authentication". In a regular Java application that problem is usually fixed by including sqljdbc_auth.dll. I have sqljdbc42.jar in the xd/lib directory, but I'm not sure what to do with sqljdbc_auth.dll. I have tried putting it in there, but no luck.

Comment: Put the location of `sqljdbc_auth.dll` on the `PATH`, that usually works.